# in R how to plot a bargraph representing the proportion of a long data

Tags: r, plot, graph

df2

```
   Meal                           Contents apple banana beef berry blackberry    cantaloupe chicken mashpotatoes redberries rice strawberry stringbeans

1 Snack_1   redberries,strawberry,blackberry     0      0    0     0              1          0       0            0          1    0          1           0
2 Snack_2           banana,apple,strawberry,     1      1    0     0          0          0       0            0          0    0          1           0
3 Snack_3                       rice,chicken     0      0    0     0          0          0       1            0          0    1          0           0
4 Snack_4      beef,stringbeans,mashpotatoes     0      0    1     0          0          0       0            1          0    0          0           1
5 Snack_5 banana,strawberry,berry,cantaloupe     0      1    0     1          0          1       0
```

I run a function to find out the top ingredients for a snack

```
 topn_v1  <- names(sort(colSums(df2[3:ncol(df2)]), decreasing=TRUE))[1:n]
```

So it resulted in something like this:

```
     Berry           10
     Strawberry     200
     Cantalopue      30
```

When I tried to plot this value it results in a points on the plot. 
But I wanted it to show bar graphs to show how each Ingredient fair with each other. Is this possible in R

Comment: You can try `geom_bar` from the `ggplot2` package (`library(ggplot2)`), with `stat = "identity"`. Assuming your resulting data frame above is called `df` with columns `Ingredient`, and `Quantity`, we can do `ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(Ingredient), y = Quantity)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")`. Reference: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_bar.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With base R & ggplot2:

```
df
     Fruit Count
1      Berry    10
2 Strawberry   200
3 Cantalopue    30

barplot(df$Count, names.arg=df$Fruit, ylab='Count')

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(Fruit, Count)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image]